# Find specific union of two arrays with different length in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, unique

I have a coding problem in Matlab, where I try to find a solution without too many for-loops slowing down the process.

I have an array that looks like:

```
A = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5]
```

Another that looks like:

```
B = [0,1,0,1,1]
```

In B there's always as many elements as their are unique elements in A and the value corresponds to the unique element in A, in other words:

```
length(unique(A)) = length(B)
```

I want to compute a result that tells me the index where B == 0 (C) and B == 1 (D) in A.

```
C = [1,2,3,9,10,11,12]
D = [4,5,6,7,8,13,14,15,16,17,18]
```

Comment: Aren't `C` and `D` backwards here?

Comment: What is your current approach? Have you taken a look at the `find` function?

Comment: @excaza thanks - I changed it

Comment: If `A = [1, 3, 4, 6]` does `length(B) == 6`?

Comment: @excaza no it's equal 4.

Comment: So how does their `value corresponds to the unique element in A`?

Comment: @excaza     `length(unique(A)) = length(B)`

Comment: Got it, the sentence was pretty confusing.

Comment: @MatthiasW. First I go through all indices i of A. Moreover I have a counter k. The first time I check if the counter k  is equal zero or one. If it is either 0 or 1 I will save all i's in C or D until A(i) changes. At that point k increases with 1. But this is just a bad for - loop and not really elegant

Comment: @Jonas: I posted a solution. But you are right, I didn't consider that your vector was sorted, this may simplify the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach: first "calculate" `Au` as unique vector of `A`. In the next step use `B` for logical indexing of `Au`: `Au(  logical(B) )` - this gets the values to be found in `A`. Then check which values are member of this group and then get their indices. There may be a simpler approach though.

```
A = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5]
Au = unique( A );
B = [0,1,0,1,1];

C = find( ismember( A, Au(  logical(B) ) ) )
D = find( ismember( A, Au( ~logical(B) ) ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, way faster than my for-loop!